# Отследить изменение блока <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dhtml, javascript-events

На сайте вывод результатов поиска — постраничный. При этом переход к другой странице происходит «прозрачно», без перезагрузки страницы целиком — меняется лишь содержимое определённого блока `<div>`.

Мне нужно вызывать `alert('Changed!')` каждый раз, как я перехожу к новой странице c результатами поиска.

1. Щелчок по номеру страницы
2. Результаты поиска загружаются фоново
3. **Перед самым отображением происходит вызов `alert('Changed!')`**
4. Страница отобразилась на экране
5. `GOTO 1`

Answer (score 1):

Если именно после завершения запроса и до вывода данных, то я вижу пока два варианта:

1. Вписать ваш `alert` перед кодом, который выводит данные на страницу (*Ваш К.О.*)
2. В jQuery, в методе `$.ajax()`, есть функция `dataFilter`, которая вызывается в момент получения данных в ответе с сервера и до вызова `success`.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       /*
       Other settings
       */
       dataFilter: function() {
           console.log('dataFilter');
       },
       success: function() {
           console.log('success');
       }
   });
   ```

`MutationObserver`, метод `complete` в `$.ajax()` и т.д. - для вашей задачи вряд ли подойдут.

P.S. Вы конечно же [почитаете документацию](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), но не забудьте, что метод `dataFilter` предназначен для кастомной обработки "сырых" данных и должен их возвращать ([пример в песочнице](https://jsfiddle.net/c4180pdb/)).

```
$.ajax({
    /*
    Other settings
    */
    dataFilter: function(data, type) {
        // some code
        return data; // necessarily!
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // output
    }
});
```

Comment: Верно, я очень далёк от принципиального понимания и некорректно сформулировал вопрос. Дело в том, что я просто хочу знать, когда именно происходят изменения нужного мне `<div>` на каком-то случайном сайте. Я не пишу код вывода на страницу. Это, вероятно, похоже на Content Script. Например, загрузив страницу, я получаю div == `div0`. Затем, «провоцируя» обновление, я остаюсь на той же самой странице, но только уже с div ==  `div1`. И так далее. P.S. Извините, если что не так.